# How to correctly use exports and subpaths on package.json using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json

It's my first time trying to create a npm package using TypeScript, and I've been experiencing some troubles, probably because I missunderstood something following the documentation.
I'm using Node 16.16.0 with npm 8.13.2 at the moment of writing this.

First of all, my project structure looks like this.

```
src/
├─ module1/
│  ├─ index.ts
├─ module2/
│  ├─ index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "@owner/mypackage",
  "version": "v1.0.0",
  ...
  "files": [
    "lib/**/*"
  ],
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    "./module1": "./lib/module1/index.js",
    "./module2": "./lib/module2/index.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  }
}
```

The thing is that, when publishing the module, it generates the following structure:

```
lib/
├─ module1/
│  ├─ index.js
├─ module2/
│  ├─ index.js
package.json
```

Leaving me with the following importing structure:

```
import {Foo} from "@owner/mypackage/lib/module1";
```

Instead of the desired one:

```
import {Foo} from "@owner/mypackage/module1";
```

How can I achieve that pattern? And, in case there is, can I improve it or follow better practices?

Comment: The published structure will be the same, but the `exports` provides an alias to those modules for systems that support it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that TS support for importing packages that use `exports` and various configurations therein is still pretty new and requires extra config in some cases.

Comment: what version of Typescript are you compiling with? Only Typescript 4.7+ supports the `exports` field.

Comment: Secondly, I'm noticing that your `type` in package.json is set to module (referring to ESM) but the tsconfig.json is set to module `commonjs`. I think these need to match as they're different. I may be wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Personally, in a project I have running [Typescript 4.7+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#package-json-exports-imports-and-self-referencing), the following has worked: what you need is the `typesVersions` property in `package.json` instead. (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#version-selection-with-typesversions)

I'll pull this quote out of the documentation above as relevance:

> Well, if none of the fields in typesVersions get matched, TypeScript falls back to the [types field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package), so here TypeScript 3.0 and earlier will be redirected to [...]/node_modules/package-name/index.d.ts.

Which essentially means, if the `typesVersions` field isn't defined in `package.json`, the `types` field is used, but the `types` field isn't helpful to us when when have multiple export paths with `exports`.

Hope this helps!

```json
{
  "exports": {
    "./module1": "./lib/module1/index.js",
    "./module2": "./lib/module2/index.js",
  },
  "typesVersions": {
     "*": {
       "module1": ["lib/module1/index.js"],
       "module2": ["lib/module2/index.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a very similar issue. Can you spot the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76236503/200987. P.S. I see your types do not have any dot prefixed, as the exports do. Is that significant?

Comment: ```
{
"./util": {
      "types": "./dist/types/util/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/esm/util.js"
    },
    "./common": {
      "types": "./dist/types/common/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/esm/common.js"
    },
  }
```


is the preferred format as TS no directly supports this syntax